# How can I select all TD elements that don't contain an A element?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to use JQuery to select all of the `TD`'s in a `table` that **DON'T** have an `A` tag inside them. (They should just have text).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("td:not(:has(a))").doStuff();
```